# Usage of 'World rotation quaternion'?

Tags: rotation, transformation, quaternion

While debugging the code that decomposes the world matrix, I found that the decomposed world rotation value is different from the world rotation value stored in Transform.

Simply, World Rotation is accumulated 'only' rotational data from root Transform, and I think it will have different results than World Matrix, which accumulates size and location values as well.

If my assumption is correct, is this rotation value not used to "make" the world matrix, but stored to obtain your relative rotation value by comparing it with the world quaternion value of the parent transform?
Or if I'm wrong, where is this world quaternion value used?

Comment: [This answer explains some of the complexities that can make a world matrix differ from a pure translation-rotation-scale triplet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/189483/39518), which might help give some context for what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

World `rotation` and world `matrix` differ; world `rotation` is for relative rotations, world `matrix` contains full transform info, both used in transform hierarchies and specific calculations.